# Make a string equal to what a named range refers to?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range called tempPrintArea
it refers to ="A1:J59"
I created it with VBA and the scope became local. I don't know if the scope matters.

I used this line to create the named range:

```
wks.Names.Add Name:="tempPrintArea", RefersTo:="A1:J59"
```

Now I want to set the value of a string to "A1:J59". I've tried the following:

```
Dim test As String
test = Range("tempPrintArea").RefersTo
```

but I get the error message Method 'Range' out of object '_Gloabl' failed

What can I change in these code lines to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using

```
wks.Names.Add Name:="tempPrintArea", RefersTo:="A1:J59"
```

code doesn't create named range that *refers* to `A1:J59`, instead code creates named range with *text* `"A1:J59"`.

[image]

For creating named range use this one instead:

```
wks.Names.Add Name:="tempPrintArea", RefersTo:=wks.Range("A1:J59")
```

and then

```
Dim test As String
test = wks.Range("tempPrintArea").Address(False, False) ' returns A1:J59
```

Comment: That's a great answer! Can you also help me with how I can access the value ="A1:J59" in VBA?

Comment: sorry, can you clarify what do you mean, please? doesn't `test = wks.Range("tempPrintArea").Address(False, False)` works for you? It returns `"A1:J59"`..

Comment: Ignore my comment. Thank you for your help!