# Add selection to named range using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range that is called tempPrintArea and refers to

```
='Label packinglist'!$A$1:$J$59
```

I want to use VBA to add another selection to it, so that it refers to

```
='Label packinglist'!$A$1:$J$59,'Label packinglist'!$A$61:$J$110
```

How can I do this?

I'm envisioning something like

Range("tempPrintArea").RefersTo = wks.Range("tempPrintArea").Address & wks.Range("$A$61:$J$110")

... but that doesn't work

Comment: do you want to add reference to exiting named range or create new named range?

Comment: I want to add the reference to the existing named range called tempPrintArea

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that you've created named range like this:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Label packinglist")

wks.Names.Add Name:="tempPrintArea", RefersTo:=wks.Range("A1:J59")
```

next step is to add new reference to it:

```
wks.Names("tempPrintArea").RefersTo = Union(wks.Range("tempPrintArea"), wks.Range("A61:J110"))
```

and now

```
Dim test As String
test = wks.Range("tempPrintArea").Address ' returns $A$1:$J$59,$A$61:$J$110
```

[image]

Comment: No need for two steps. The second step will overwrite any existing name, so it is all you need.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers, I know, first part follows from another OP's question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012097/make-a-string-equal-to-what-a-named-range-refers-to and I've decided to leave it